# Function str_replace do not work

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a problem with the function str_replace(). I have this code:

```
$headImageName = "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\realitka/headImages/hImageMini4e7b5a6ea8c95Pyro.png";

die(var_dump(str_replace("C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\realitka/", "", $headImageName)));
```

And the result of var_dump is again:

```
string(88) "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\realitka/headImages/hImageMini4e7b5bae39148Pyro.png"
```

Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\r` in a double quoted string has special meaning.

PHP interpret it as carriage return character.

Either use single quotes:

```
str_replace('C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\realitka/', "", $headImageMiniName)
```

Or escape all your slashes:

```
str_replace("C:\\Program Files\\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\\www\\realitka/", "", $headImageMiniName)
```

See the **[list of escape sequences in double-quoted strings](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `\` symbols:

```
str_replace("C:\\Program Files\\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\\www\\realitka/", "", $headImageName)
```